# Number of pairs of functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $f,g$ be functions such that $f: X\to Y$ and $g:Y \to X$.

If $X = \{1,\ldots ,m\}$ and $Y = \{1, \ldots ,n\}$ with $m<n$, and $g\circ f$ is the identity on $X$, then how many possibilities are there for the pairs of functions $f$ and $g$?

If $g \circ f$ is the identity then $f$ is injective, so each $x \in X$ can go to at most one $y \in Y$. So we have $n$ choices for where the 1st element goes, $n−1$ choices for the where the 2nd element goes, ... , $n−(m−1)$ choices for where the mth element goes. How we choose to define our $f$ uniquely defines our $g$ for where it sends $f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(m)$, but we still have $n−m$ remaining elements that can go anywhere in $X$. So overall we have $n(n−1)\cdots(n−(m−1))m(m−1)⋯(m−(n−m−1))$ choices for $f,g$. How is this?

Comment: What are your thoughts and ideas? In what context did this problem arise?  Unless you give more background, your question will attract downvotes.

Comment: Please explain the reasoning for your answer.

Comment: If $g\circ f$ is identity, then what information can you deduce about $f?$ Is $f$ injective? If yes, then how many injections from $X$ to $Y$ is possible?

Comment: If $g\circ f$ is the identity then $f$ is injective, so each $x\in X$ can go to at most one $y\in Y$. So we have $n$ choices for where the 1st element goes, $n-1$ choices for the where the 2nd element goes, ... , $n-(m-1)$ choices for where the mth element goes. How we choose to define our $f$ uniquely defines our $g$ for where it sends $f(1), f(2), \ldots ,f(m)$, but we still have $n-m$ remaining elements that can go anywhere in $X$. So overall we have $n(n-1)\cdots (n-(m-1))m(m-1)\cdots (m-(n-m-1))$ choices for $f,g$. How is this?

Answer (score 1):

> If $g \circ f$ is the identity then $f$ is injective, so each $x \in X$ can go to at most one $y \in Y$. So we have $n$ choices for where the 1st element goes, $n−1$ choices for the where the 2nd element goes, ... , $n−(m−1)$ choices for where the mth element goes. How we choose to define our $f$ uniquely defines our $g$ for where it sends $f(1),f(2),\ldots,f(m)$, but we still have $n−m$ remaining elements that can go anywhere in $X$.

So far, so good.

> So overall we have $n(n−1)\cdots(n−(m−1))m(m−1)⋯(m−(n−m−1))$ choices for $f,g$.

This contradicts your assertion that the $n - m$ remaining elements can go anywhere in $X$.  Since the remaining $n - m$ elements in $Y$ can be mapped to any of the elements in $X$, there are $m$ possible images for each of the $n - m$ elements in $Y$ that are not in the range of $f$.  Thus, the number of functions $g: Y \to X$ such that $g \circ f$ is the identity on $X$ is $m^{n - m}$.

For example, suppose $X = \{1, 2\}$ and $Y = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.  Let $f: X \to Y$ be the function defined by $f(x) = x$.  Then there are $2^{5 - 2} = 2^3 = 8$ functions $g: Y \to X$ such that $g \circ f$ is the identity on $X$.  They are:

$$
\begin{array}{c c c c c c}
k & g_k(1) & g_k(2) & g_k(3) & g_k(4) & g_k(5)\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2\\
3 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
4 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2\\
5 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1\\
6 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2\\
7 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
8 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{array}
$$

Since there are
$$P(n, m) = n(n - 1)(n - 2) \cdots [n - (m - 1)]$$
functions $f: X \to Y$ such that $f$ is injective, the number of pairs of functions $f: X \to Y$, $g: Y \to X$, where $X = \{1, \ldots, m\}$ and $Y = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ with $m < n$, such that $g \circ f$ is the identity on $X$ is
$$P(n, m)m^{n - m}$$